Kovetz Mefarshim by daf
Has anyone ever put out mefarshim on gemara by daf rather than mefaresh? Or try to collect primary rishonim/achronim discussed in yeshivot per daf and reprint them together?

I assume you're looking for a feature which is available at HebrewBooks.org using the Meforshim dropdown https://hebrewbooks.org/shas

I'd consider the classic שיטה מקובצת and modern קובץ שיטות קמאי as being adjacent to what you are asking for...

Yes, someone has. Here is a link to their website
https://ozvehadar.us/kovetz-mefarshim/

You should consider אוצר מפרשי התלמוד
It references in extenso rishonim and aharonim al seder hadaf. I think it corresponds to what you are looking for.
You can see here one page of the sefer

Welcome to MiYodeya John and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Typically for a question like this, it would be great to hear a few reasons why you recommend this particular reference book. Great to have you learn with us!

Kovetz Shittos Kamai compiled by Reb Shalom Meir Yungerman is exactly what you're looking for. Most of the volumes on shas are available on Hebrewbooks.
